# String.replaceAll letting some chars through the cracks

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

So I'm working with a huge dataset in Java trying to scrub the text of everything but alpha characters. Right now I'm doing this with:

```
snippet = snippet.toLowerCase();
snippet.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
```

however the sanitization is not going as planned. Some extraneous `@`, `#`, `?`, and `:` are making their way through. Ideas?

Comment: if you're doing `snippet.toLowerCase();` then you don't need `[^A-Za-z]`, you can just use `[^a-z]`. You probably should, because anything that remains upper case after a `toLowerCase()` did not start off as an upper case letter in the first place. The only way I can think of this happening is reading a utf-8 string as an ascii char string.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In java, [Strings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable) are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable) - their value can't be changed. Consequently, [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) *returns* the altered String; it doesn't *change* the String on which it was called.

You must *assign* the return value back to the variable:

```
snippet = snippet.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z]", "");
```

Although this behaviour at first seems "non Object Oriented", when the class is immutable it does make sense.

Also, you don't need the call to `.toLowerCase()` - you regex is matching on uppercase letters too.